# Replace '&' with '&amp;' in xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I am writing an xsl for an xml, but I am stuck at `&` in my xml.
It shows error like `A semi colon character was expected. Error processing resource..`.

Now I want all `&` to be replaced with `&amp;`. so that it won't show any error.

How can I achieve this?

Is there any alternative way of fixing this problem?

Comment: I think CDATA is used prevent this.

Comment: I guess it's not possible with XSLT as the XML is not well formed (see the error you're getting). XSLT needs well formed XML. You should use a text editor's search and replace functionality or maybe sed/awk.

Comment: Well, that's not strictly true, you should be able to parse the file as text.  However you'd be better off using sed/awk or some other regex solution (perl?) as a pre-processing step.

Comment: Also if you do that, be wary of replacing valid &amp; with &amp;amp;

Comment: How these XML files were created at first instance..

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582556/handling-special-characters-in-xsl/13583664#13583664

Comment: @ThomasW, This *can* be done using XSLT 2.0 and reading the problematic text with the `unparsed-text()` function -- then using the `replace()` function (or `<xsl:analyze-string>`)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Yes, I saw your suggestion. Nice proof of concept! But as you said yourself, it's a question of hammer and nail...

Comment: @ThomasW, Not exactly -- RegEx is with the same power, whether you use it from C# or from XSLT. Also, in XSLT 3.0 one can use for the second stage the new function `parse-xml()`, thus doing all the processing -- the escaping, the parsing and the whatever following processing  -- just in a single transformation.

Comment: @ThomasW it really doesn't matter, but it was my suggestion - very rare for me to get there before Dimitre! :)

Comment: @yamahito Sorry for the misattribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with XSL - it operates on well-formed XML input only.

You need to use some search & replace functionality, for instance sed:

```
sed -i 's:&:&amp;:' yourfile.xml
```

Or even better:

```
sed -i 's:&:&amp;:g;s:amp;amp;:amp;:g;' yourfile.xml
```

which prevents you from replacing correct entity references.

Comment: Absolutely is possible with XSL (see my answer) - but you have to treat the input as unparsed text.

Comment: nice trick :) but requires additional (well-formed) file as the processing input; why not, perhaps it better fits the given usecase

Comment: @Michael Kay: do you mean 'A transformation may now be invoked by calling a named template' in the xslt20 spec? I could not find anything closer... can you send a specific link? thanks

Answer (score 1):

So here's an answer.  Replace the $input parameter with your input file.  Run against any valid XML file - NOT your input file as the input - the script will ignore it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="input" select="'file:/U:/input.txt'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="unparsed-text($input)" regex="&amp;">
      <xsl:matching-substring><xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text></xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of></xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PS - I leave this as a proof of concept rather than a suggested solution to your underlying problem.  XSLT is not the best tool for this job (just because all you have is a hammer doesn't mean you should treat everything like a nail).

Comment: You'll want to do more with that regex to avoid 'correcting' already valid entities.  You might want to use named templates to nest several levels of analyze string to get more entities corrected if you also have issues with &quot; &apos; etc - correcting < and > would be a nightmare!