# Handling special characters in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, special-characters

I have an xml that contains some special characters like `&` and `whitespaces`.

I want to handle these special characters in xsl.
How can I handle special characters in xsl?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cpdhtml.xsl"?>
<pmd-cpd>
    <duplication lines="72" tokens="75">
        <file line="632" path="M:\PBA0039 & Code\Common\ssc\src\Main.c"/>
        <file line="1802" path="M:\PBA0039 & Code\Common\ssc\src\link1.c"/>
    </duplication>
</pmd-cpd>
```

Here you can see `&` in `path`. It gives error while transforming xml.
Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: That's not well-formed XML, you need to fix the unescaped `&` at source before you can process it with XSLT.

Comment: @IanRoberts This xml is generated by some tool. Like in example, some folder names may contain `&`. So how can I replace it with '&amp;'?

Comment: The tool needs to be fixed to produce well formed XML. XSL cannot operate on files that are not well formed XML.

Comment: OK... Thanks for youiformation.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can read this as a regular text (not xml) file and replace all occurences of " & " with " &amp; ". That escapes the "&" characters and produces the textual representation of a well-formed XML document. Then you can process this XML document with your XSLT code.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: It might work for the sample given, but that's a very unreliable 'fix'- there's no guarantee there will be a space either side of a `&`. Personally, the only acceptable solution is that whatever tool generates this document should be corrected to output valid XML.

Comment: @Flynn1179, It is possible to specify a correct regex for entity, and using these, leave syntactically-valid entity-references as they are, without change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [escape them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters), as you do in any XML document.

The escape for `&` is `&amp;`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cpdhtml.xsl"?>
<pmd-cpd>
    <duplication lines="72" tokens="75">
        <file line="632" path="M:\PBA0039 &amp; Code\Common\ssc\src\Main.c"/>
        <file line="1802" path="M:\PBA0039 &amp; Code\Common\ssc\src\link1.c"/>
    </duplication>
</pmd-cpd>
```

Comment: How to escape '&' with '&amp;'. I cant do it manually, need to achieve this using xsl only.

Comment: @SachinMhetre - Do you mean the XML has `&` like that? That it isn't `&amp;`? If so **it is not valid XML**. You need valid XML in order to use XSL.

Comment: This xml is generated by some tool. Like in example, some folder names may contain `&`. So how can I replace it with '&amp;'?

Comment: @SachinMhetre - The tool is producing **invalid XML**. You need to fix the tool and the invalid XML it produces. XSL **cannot** be used for this.

Comment: @SachinMhetre - once again. You **don't have XML**. The file is **not** valid XML. It is not well formed. XSL can only work on well formed XML files. The issue is that `&` by itself is not valid in XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess these XML files were generated by string concatenation .. otherwise there is no way you would end up with uncoded XML.

Only way you can get rid of special characters is to use any programming language like C#, VB.NET and load the file as string.. 
use string manipulation operations..

```
string.Replace("&","&amp;");
```

**updated per Flynn1179's comment:**

if you are afraid of running into an issue, where your XML already have some characters encoded.. then add one more line:

```
string.Replace("&amp;amp;","&amp;");
```

Well the better solution would be to modify the code which is generating such XML files..

example: usage of XML DOM instead of String-concat

Comment: You need to be very careful doing that- if the document contains a well escaped `&amp;`, you'll replace it with `&amp;amp;` in error. You really need to check that each occurrence of `&` is not already part of an XML entity.

Comment: @Flynn1179, the same thought came across my mind.. but it is also possible that user wants to show `&amp;` as is in output!!

Comment: so really can't be sure what is user's requirement here. If he wants to get rid of such duplicates then he can go for `string.Replace("&amp;amp;","&amp;");`

Comment: Yeah, but that's just getting messier. Far too often I've seen very messy 'workarounds' that fix bad output from pre-existing code, it's preferable to correct the output in wherever you're data's coming from in cases like this. Don't get me wrong, it's a good answer in this case, it just shouldn't be necessary to do stuff like this.

Comment: @Flynn1179, agreed with you .. ! I hate such code which generates XML by using string-concatenation, Even I have come across such once! I chose to the code since it's a better solution .. This answer is to provide additional solution if OP is really helpless to do that..

Answer (score 0):

You can not use XSLT to transform an XML file if it is not valid. To keep excaping characters in your xml, you can use CDATA section in your XML. Then you can safely use XSLT to pick those CDATA.
Check this following post on how to use CDATA to keep escaping characters.

http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/11/extracting-cdata-section-using-xslt.html